# SPDataSource for asp gridView returns nothing?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, spquery, splist, gridview

I'm binding my SPDataSource to an ASP:DataGrid but it returns empty gridview not filled.
Here's my aspx file

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" ID="SPTypes" DataSourceMode="ListItem" UseInternalName="true"> 
</SharePoint:SPDataSource> 
<asp:gridView ID="GV" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Title"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" >
    <columns>
        <asp:boundfield DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title">
        </asp:boundfield>
    </columns>
</asp:gridView>
```

and here's the code behind

```
SPList corrList = getSelectedList("Correspondance");
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList taskList = web.Lists["Tasks"];
SPTypes.List = taskList;
SPTypes.SelectCommand = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/>" +
        "<Value Type=\"Text\">Document interne</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Fonction\"/>" +
        "<Value Type=\"Text\">GenerateChrono</Value></Eq></And></Where>";

GV.DataSource = SPTypes;
GV.DataBind();
```

I checked the query and it returns many items I even tried to put the query this way :

```
SPTypes.SelectCommand = "<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/>" +
        "<Value Type=\"Text\">Document interne</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Fonction\"/>" +
        "<Value Type=\"Text\">GenerateChrono</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>";
```

PS title is the internal name I want to retrieve !

Comment: Glolita, try using [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glolita,

Use SPGridView instead of ASP:GridView...

Here is a nice article: [How to use the SPGridView filter together with a SPDataSource](http://insomniacgeek.com/how-to-use-the-spgridview-filter-together-with-a-spdatasource/)

I also noticed in every example in CAML before `<Query>` they are using `<View>`, but I don't know if this is really the problem... can you please try that as well

Also,

```
SPTypes.DataSourceMode="List"
```

Hope this resolves the issue!

Comment: it still display nothing !

Comment: I just edited the answer, follow the Blog given!

Comment: yeah I noticed that too and I tried to put <view> as well and also nothing !

Comment: set SPTypes.DataSourceMode="List"

Comment: YESSSS !!! :D now it worked ! thx a lot !!

Comment: just one more question if I want to add more boundfields their DataField property should be set to only values declared in DataKeyNames SPGridView Property or what kind Of changes should I make ?

Comment: Glolita, [Samples on how to use SharePoint's GridView](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Ejemplos-sobre-cmo-usar-el-69cd5f16) - I hope this will answer all your questions.. I am glad it helped!